# python wordpress rest API response 401 error

Tags: python, wordpress, python-requests, wordpress-rest-api

I'm making Python Wordpress REST API, but I'm getting response 401 error, can you help?

```
import requests
import base64
import json

url = "https://helloworld.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"

user = "admin"
password = "***********"

credentials = user + ':' + password
token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode())

header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}

post = {
 'title'    : 'Hello World',
 'status'   : 'publish', 
 'content'  : 'This is my first post created using rest API',
 'date'   : '2021-06-29T10:00:00'
}

responce = requests.post(url , data=json.dumps(post), headers=header)
print(responce)
```

Answer (score 0):

401 Unauthorized eror. May you need to check username or pasword.
You need install application password.
EDİT
you need to write your admin user name and write pasword where get it application password.
[dont write this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeLgK.png)